# Set dynamic 2 key column

Tags: azure

how to get 2 key columns dynamically,

@createArray(activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.column_name1,activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.column_name2)

I need to get 2 key columns dynamically
Please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Could please provide more details about what you want to do and what you have tried?

Comment: Could you please provide your required input and output?

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To pass key columns dynamically you need to follow below steps:

[image]

pass the below expression:

```
@createArray(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.column1name,activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.column2name)
```

if you are getting key column as `column1,column2` from lookup then you need to use split function to separate them and form an array.